# CMake find_path is not finding path in simple example

Tags: cmake

Find_path just does not work for me at all under any circumstances, so I constructed what I thought was the simplest possible test case.

My directory structure for source code contains

```
E:/Include/fred.h
E:/Src/fizzbuzz/CMakeLists.txt
E:/Src/fizzbuzz/fizzbuzz.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project (fizzbuzz)
find_path(
    GSLINCLUDE
    NAMES "fred.h"
    PATHS ../..   E:/
)
message(STATUS "GSLINCLUDE => ${GSLINCLUDE}")
add_executable(fizzbuzz fizzbuzz.cpp stdafx.h)
```

which gives me the result:

```
-- GSLINCLUDE => GSLINCLUDE-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: E:/src/fizzbuzz
```

Presumably I am doing something simple and obviously wrong in each and every case, but what would work in this simple example with this extremely simple directory structure?

And if CMake is just not expecting such a simple directory structure, what directory structure would make it happy?

Comment: What I would like to do is give CMake some guesses about where the include files are, and have it make sure the files are in one of those places, and then 

    include_directories(GSL_INCLUDE)

Answer (score 11):

in brief, `find_path` is not recursive, so if you want something to be found in *Include* subfolder, you have 2 options:

state path file should reside (note `E:/Include` instead of `E:/`):

```
find_path(
    GSLINCLUDE
    NAMES "fred.h"
    PATHS ../..   E:/Include
)
```

other option is to use `PATH_SUFFIXES` modifier:

```
find_path(
    GSLINCLUDE
    NAMES "fred.h"
    PATHS ../..   E:/
    PATH_SUFFIXES Include
)
```

At the end, here is the complete documentation about [find_path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/find_path.html?highlight=i)